# Setting up a C++ Mex function with Visual Studio and Intel MKL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, mex, intel-mkl

I am using a [visual studio template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gharveymn.MEXFunctionTemplates) to produce Matlab MEX functions. Using this template alone, I can compile functions from Visual Studio using either Visual Studio's compiler or one of the Intel C++/DPC++ compilers. However, when I include mkl libraries, I encounter an error at the include line saying "cannot open source file mkl.h"

I have included and linked all the relevant directories and libraries. Here are the command lines from the configuration properties in visual studio. Why could this be happening?

C/C++ Properties:

```
/GS /TP /W3 /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\include" 
/I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2023a\extern\include\" /I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2023a\simulink\include\" /Z7 /O2 /Zp8 /D "USE_MEX_CMD" 
/D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_SECURE_SCL=0" 
/D "MATLAB_MEX_FILE" /D "__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER=20230100" /D "_WINDLL" /Zc:forScope /GR 
/MD /Fa"C:\Users\nikun\source\repos\JCFMKL\JCFMKL\build\x64\Release\" /EHs 
/nologo /Fo"C:\Users\nikun\source\repos\JCFMKL\JCFMKL\build\x64\Release\" 
//fprofile-instr-use "C:\Users\nikun\source\repos\JCFMKL\JCFMKL\build\x64\Release\" 
/Fp"C:\Users\nikun\source\repos\JCFMKL\JCFMKL\build\x64\Release\JCFMKL.pch"
```

Linker Properties

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\nikun\source\repos\JCFMKL\bin\x64\Release\JCFMKL.mexw64" /MANIFEST 
/NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\nikun\source\repos\JCFMKL\bin\x64\Release\JCFMKL.mexw64.pdb" 
/DYNAMICBASE "mkl_rt.lib" "mkl_intel_c.lib" "mkl_intel_thread.lib" "mkl_intel_lp64.lib" 
"mkl_core.lib" "libiomp5md.lib" "libmx.lib" "libmex.lib" "libmat.lib" 
"libMatlabDataArray.lib" "libMatlabEngine.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" 
"winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" 
"uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" 
/IMPLIB:"C:\Users\nikun\source\repos\JCFMKL\bin\x64\Release\JCFMKL.lib" /DLL /MACHINE:X64 
/INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/ManifestFile:"C:\Users\nikun\source\repos\JCFMKL\JCFMKL\build\x64\Release\JCFMKL.mexw64.int
ermediate.manifest" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\lib\intel64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program 
Files\MATLAB\R2023a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft\" /TLBID:1
```

Comment: Does a file called "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\include\mkl.h" exist? How are you including the file in your source file, as `#include <mkl.h>` or `#include "mkl.h"`?

Comment: Yes it does exist. I tried both, both result in the same issue. The program files for Intel also seem to include multiple folders that appear like different copies of the 'latest' directory. I tried including each of the corresponding include directories. No luck..

Comment: Turns out I'm just an idiot. I was changing the paths for the release build but trying to compile the Debug build....................................................................

Comment: MKL installation: Could you please try checking the installation if everything went well?
Build Configuration: Could you please check if the configuration settings were been updated under the correct configuration and platform?  (x64 or x86) and the same was been used to build and run your project?
Intel Libraries for oneAPI: Could you please make sure, you have enabled Intel oneMKL, interfaces libraries accordingly under the Intel Libraries for oneAPI of the configuration properties?  In the project properties, under the "Linker" section, go to "Additional Library Directories" add req files